# Old wiring into new light switch

Tags: wiring, switch, light

I'm trying to replace an old light switch. I was thinking that I'd have to pigtail all the neutrals and all the hot and the grounds but that caused an arc so I'm not sure how to go about wiring these into a new light switch.
This light switch has three hots three neutrals and three grounds. It powers two lights and an outlet I believe.
[image]

Comment: If you got an arc, you connected a hot to a neutral. All white wires are not neutrals. All neutrals are white, but some white wires are used for hot or switched hot. I think it might be best for you to call an electrician.

Comment: Could it be a three-way switch?

Comment: "Dumb" switches don't have or need Neutrals. So if a white wire was connected to a switch it's almost certainly not a Neutral. What are you showing us in your pic? Is that the original configuration or is that how it is now? At least some of the wires appear to be disconnected, but with all the dust & crud it's hard to make out clearly what's going on there.

Comment: Whatever that thing is, it has way too many terminals to be a SPST.  I'm counting 5 terminals here.

Comment: SPST could have given terminals if two are convenience passthroughs and one is ground, but since I don't recognize the device I have no opinions.